# How to get highest high, lowest low and close of a session in pine script tradingview

Tags: pine-script

I want to get highest high and lowest low and close of a particular session.
can any one know about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following code:

```
//@version=4
//@author=LucF, for PineCoders
study("Session hi/lo", "", true)
noPlotOutside = input(true, "Don't plot outside of hours")
showHi = input(true, "Show highs")
showLo = input(true, "Show lows")
srcHi = input(high, "Source for Highs")
srcLo = input(low, "Source for Lows")
timeAllowed = input("1200-1500", "Allowed hours", input.session)

// Check to see if we are in allowed hours using session info on all 7 days of the week.
timeIsAllowed = time(timeframe.period, timeAllowed + ":1234567")
var hi = 10e-10
var lo = 10e10
if timeIsAllowed
    // We are entering allowed hours; reset hi/lo.
    if not timeIsAllowed[1]
        hi := srcHi
        lo := srcLo
    else
        // We are in allowed hours; track hi/lo.
        hi := max(srcHi, hi)
        lo := min(srcLo, lo)

plot(showHi and not(noPlotOutside and not timeIsAllowed)? hi : na, "Highs", color.blue, 3, plot.style_circles)
plot(showLo and not(noPlotOutside and not timeIsAllowed)? lo : na, "Lows", color.fuchsia, 3, plot.style_circles)
```

https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-can-i-track-highslows-for-a-specific-period-of-time

Comment: thank you @Starr Lucky but do you know how to get close of the session ?